# Pygame Joystick event disturbed by something when simulating alt+tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, keyboard-python

I made a script with pygame and keyboard to simulate a keyboard press when a controller button is pressed and it worked perferctly, but when trying to simulate an `alt tab`, `pygame` is doing something weird. Here is an example showing the code used to try an simulate alt+tab by pressing A and B on a XBox controller:

```py
import pygame
from keyboard import press, release

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

Joy = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
Joy.init()

xbox_A_button_index = 0  # PS alternative: 2 for X
xbox_B_button_index = 1  # PS alternative: 1 for O
xbox_BACK_button_index = 6  # PS alternative: 8 for SHARE

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (
            event.type == pygame.QUIT
            or (  # Quit if the user presses BACK on the controller or the window is closed
                event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN
                and event.button == xbox_BACK_button_index
            )
        ):
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == xbox_A_button_index:
                print("+ Alt")
                press("alt")

            if event.button == xbox_B_button_index:
                print("+ Tab")
                press("tab")

        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == xbox_A_button_index:
                print("- Alt")
                release("alt")

            if event.button == xbox_B_button_index:
                print("- Tab")
                release("tab")
```

When pressing A, then B, then releasing A and finally B, the above script gives me the following:

```
pygame 2.4.0 (SDL 2.26.4, Python 3.10.11)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
+ Alt
+ Tab
- Alt
- Tab
+ Alt
- Alt
```

We should get something like:

```
pygame 2.4.0 (SDL 2.26.4, Python 3.10.11)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
+ Alt
+ Tab
-Tab
-Alt
```

We should note that we ‘alt tab’ from the window, but I don't think it is the origin of the problem. I've tried pressing and releasing key with `win32api` and `win32com` to see if it has something to do with `keyboard` module but nothing changed, I have no idea why this is happening and I did not find anything about this.

Any insight or suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is the problem of handling the events only once a frame. means, if you want to check for events that combine joystick and keyboard events, then you should store the event into a variable that can then be checked next frame, something like this:

```
class InputHandler:
  """ not tested, just as idea"""
  def __init__(self):
    self.joy_button_down = False
    self.alt_pressed = False
    self.tab_pressed = False
    ...ect

  def handle_events(self, events):
    if event.type == pygame.K_TAB:
      self.tab_pressed = True
            
    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
      if event.button == xbox_A_button_index:
         self.joy_button_down = True
    ...ect
    # then, next frame it can check for:
    if self.joy_button_down and self.tab_pressed:
       do_something()
```